# Save without get lastInsertId

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a old database in PostgreSQL with **multiple primary key**.

When I try save any information in these tables, an error occurred because **CakePHP** trying to get the **lastInsertId**. Because, as we know, CakePHP doesn't support *multiple primary key*.

So, I wanna know, how can I disable this functionality/option?

I tried this, but doesn't work as expected.

```
$this->OrderDrinkBase->saveAll(
    $drinkBases,
    array('callbacks' => false, 'validate' => false)
);
```

---

The solution above, works, so I approved the answer.
But, I really want a explanation of how can I disable the function lastInsertId in CakePHP in some cases.

Comment: sorry question is not clear,please can you explain bit more

Comment: @Er.KT I revised the question, see now please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code

```
class GroupToUser extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'GroupToUser';
    var $useTable = 'groups_users';

    var $primaryKeyArray = array('user_id','group_id');

    function exists($reset = false) {
        if (!empty($this->__exists) && $reset !== true) {
            return $this->__exists;
        }
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($this->primaryKeyArray as $pk) {
            if (isset($this->data[$this->alias][$pk]) && $this->data[$this->alias][$pk]) {
                $conditions[$this->alias.'.'.$pk] = $this->data[$this->alias][$pk];
            }
            else {
                $conditions[$this->alias.'.'.$pk] = 0;
            }
        }
        $query = array('conditions' => $conditions, 'fields' => array($this->alias.'.'.$this->primaryKey), 'recursive' => -1, 'callbacks' => false);
        if (is_array($reset)) {
            $query = array_merge($query, $reset);
        }
        if ($exists = $this->find('first', $query)) {
            $this->__exists = 1;
            $this->id = $exists[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey];
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return parent::exists($reset);
        }
    }

}
```

for more information look at here http://mrphp.com.au/blog/multiple-primary-keys-cakephp#.UhxzGD90klQ

or this http://miljenkobarbir.com/using-multiple-column-primary-key-in-cakephp-cascade-delete-problem/

Comment: I'll test my friend and send you a feedback later. Thanks.

Comment: Works if I inform the `$primaryKey = user_id` too. Anyway, thanks. This is work for a while.